# Vim Conceal not working for double equals

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to write a custom conceal script to replace `==` by `≈`.

However, my syntax match seems to be working only when I put `=` and not `==`.

### content.js

```
var body = document.body;
if (body == 'body')
    console.log('yes');
```

### javascript.vim

Everything works fine when I do this:

```
syntax match jsEqual "=" conceal cchar=≈
```

When I change it to:

```
syntax match jsEqual "==" conceal cchar=≈
```

Nothing is concealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this with the [vim javascript syntax plugin](https://github.com/jelera/vim-javascript-syntax.git), but not with the built-in syntax script. That extended syntax defines a syntax group `javaScriptOpSymbols` for `==`.

To find out which syntax group causes the highlighting. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin.

To make your conceal group apply, you need to make it applicable inside that syntax group that covers the `==`; this is done via the `:help :syn-containedin` attribute:

```
syntax match jsEqual "==" conceal cchar=≈ containedin=javaScriptOpSymbols
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using a plugin named `vim-javascript`, and the group was `jsParenIfElse`. But yeah, thanks for clarifying.